# Neo4j LifecycleException in method org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase()

Tags: java, neo4j, nosql

I have a maven project which uses neo4j. I'm getting the following error when calling the method `newGraphDatabase()` through Eclipse IDE -

```
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader@5cdd7cc3 from NONE to STOPPED
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:388)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
    at com.impetus.client.neo4j.Neo4JClientFactory.createPoolOrConnection(Neo4JClientFactory.java:110)
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.GenericClientFactory.load(GenericClientFactory.java:119)
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientMetadataBuilder.buildClientFactoryMetadata(ClientMetadataBuilder.java:55)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.configureClientFactories(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:408)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.configure(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.impetus.client.neo4j.imdb.IMDBTestBase.init(IMDBTestBase.java:193)
    at com.impetus.client.neo4j.imdb.IMDBCRUDTest.setUp(IMDBCRUDTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource$1 overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneIndexProvider.load(LuceneIndexProvider.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.loadIndexImplementations(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1181)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DefaultKernelExtensionLoader.init(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1153)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:382)
    ... 41 more
```

But when I'm building the project from shell using `mvn clean install`, the test cases run without any error. Please help me. Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.impetus</groupId>
        <artifactId>kundera</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>kundera-neo4j</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>kundera-neo4j</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kundera Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>kundera-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>fallback-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>kundera-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.5.0</version> -->
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jakarta-regexp</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jakarta-regexp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Neo4J Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey - REST Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is 
                    org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default. -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> The destination file for the code coverage report has to 
                be set to the same value in the parent pom and in each module pom. Then JaCoCo 
                will add up information in the same report, so that, it will give the cross-module 
                code coverage. <destFile>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile> 
                </configuration> <executions> <execution> <id>post-test</id> <configuration> 
                <skip>true</skip> </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That caused by of `java.lang.VerifyError` is very weird.  Best guess -- is it possible you have two versions of neo4j and/or lucene on your $CLASSPATH here?  You should consider pasting into your question your dependencies on neo4j and lucene from your `pom.xml`, something's funky.

Comment: amend output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

Remove/exclude the wrong version of Lucene from your dependencies.

Neo4j uses Lucene 3.6.2

Comment: I tried that, removed incompatible dependency but its still giving the error. And when I run through shell, i dont get error.